# When using web.py how can I checkis a parameter exists in the URL?

Tags: python, web.py

I'm using web.py  https://webpy.org/ for providng access to simple python script  like
http://hosturl.com.scriptname?param1=something&param2=somethingelse

I see how I can retrieve the values of the parameters using

```
import web
param1 = web.input().param1
param2 = web.input().param2
```

However I'm stuck when I try to check if the param2, for example, even exists.

I've tried

```
if web.input().param2:
```

but that gives me an error message

```
<class 'AttributeError'> at /getmonthlyPV
```

Answer (score 0):

Groan....

what I needed was

```
if hasattr(web.input(),"param2"):
```

Alot to be said for reading the error messages, they're actually trying to help :(